# Вывести на экран номера положительных двузначных элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Программа запрашивает у пользователя элементы массива. Юзер вводит любые элементы типа `int`. Программа должна вывести на экран номера элементов массива, являющихся положительными двузначными числами. Не могу понять, как вывести именно индексы элементов массива.
Мой код:

```
massiv = input("Введите элементы массива...").split()
massiv2 = list(map(int, massiv))
a = len(massiv2)
for i in range a:
    if (massiv2[i] > 0) and (тут должна быть проверка, двузначное ли число):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if 9 < arr[i] < 100:
        print(i)
```

`arr` - список чисел

---

В вашем коде после `if` добавьте `print(i)`

Чтобы они выводилось на одной строчке, то добавьте `end=" "` в `print`:`print(i, end=" ")`

Comment: В таком случае, номера элементов будут выводится каждый с новой строки?

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант:

```py
arr = " 100 2 22 11 20 7 10 122 30 -5 11111 -334234 ".split()
arr = ' '.join(str(i) for i, v in enumerate(arr) if 9 < int(v) < 100)
print(arr)
```

Comment: зачем тут enumerate?

Comment: @Jack_oS, чтобы индекс получить и еще, я думаю, [он быстрее чем range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150762/pythonic-range-vs-enumerate-in-python-for-loop)